# Upgrade from one version of windows 7 to another?

Tags: windows-7, upgrade, installation

I have an upgrade disk for windows 7 Pro, but I need to install on a blank machine so I'm looking at buying a full retail version.  My question is, if I buy win 7 home premium, can I upgrade to pro with my other disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, however this is a **very** expensive way of doing it.

This being said, if you have any edition of Windows XP or Vista (Not OEM) that you are legally allowed to install on this machine, this can count as your previous version of Windows - then using your Windows 7 upgrade disk, you can do a fresh/custom install.

-- Just checked, you cannot use anytime upgrade - the fastest way to change editions as you need a separate anytime upgrade key and not just a new key.

Comment: You cannot use ANY edition of XP or Vista - you can use any NON-OEM edition OR the OEM edition that came with the computer.  Otherwise, you can use any OTHER edition and install that.

Comment: The important thing is that I can use another version of 7 as my existing OS to upgrade from.